# Problema realizando inserciones

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un código de MySQL el cual debe llevar 4 inserciones y consultas con WHERE.

Todo el código básico con MySQL funciona perfecto pero cuando llega el momento de insertar los valores me da un error:

> insert into empleado_consulta values ('1','4')
>
> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`guia08`.`empleado_consulta`, CONSTRAINT `empleado_consulta_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_consulta`) REFERENCES `consulta` (`id_consulta`))

Ya revisé la parte de `empleado_consulta` y las llaves foráneas, pero yo veo todo bien.

Espero me puedan ayudar porfavor

```
CREATE DATABASE guia08;
USE guia08;
CREATE TABLE cargo(
id_cargo INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
descripcion VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE paciente(
expediente INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
nombres VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
apellidos VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
telefono1 CHAR(9),
direccion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
telefono_contacto VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
INDEX p_nombres(nombres),
INDEX p_apellidos(apellidos)
);

CREATE TABLE medicamento(
idmedicamento INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
presentacion ENUM('..') NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE especialidad(
    idespecialidad INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    descripcion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE medico(
jvpm INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_especialidad INT(4) NOT NULL,
nombres VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
apellidos VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
telefono1 VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
telefono2 VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
direccion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
INDEX m_nombres(nombres),
INDEX m_apellidos(apellidos),
INDEX m_id_especialidad(id_especialidad)
);

CREATE TABLE consulta (
id_consulta INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
exp_paciente INT(11) NOT NULL,
jvpm_medico INT(11) NOT NULL,
fecha_consulta DATETIME,
tipo ENUM ('...'),
FOREIGN KEY(exp_paciente) REFERENCES paciente(expediente),
FOREIGN KEY(jvpm_medico) REFERENCES medico(jvpm),
INDEX c_exp_paciente(exp_paciente),
INDEX c_jvpm_medico(jvpm_medico),  
INDEX c_tipo(tipo)
);


CREATE TABLE medicamento_consulta(
    id_consulta INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_medicamento INT(11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_consulta) REFERENCES consulta(id_consulta),
    INDEX id_medicamento(id_medicamento)
); 


CREATE TABLE empleado(
id_empleado INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_cargo INT(4) NOT NULL,
nombres VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
apellidos VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
dui CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
direccion VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id_cargo) REFERENCES cargo(id_cargo),
INDEX e_nombres(nombres),
INDEX e_apellidos(apellidos),
INDEX e_dui(dui),
INDEX e_id_cargo(id_cargo)
);

CREATE TABLE empleado_consulta(
id_consulta INT (11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_empleado INT(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id_empleado) REFERENCES empleado(id_empleado),
FOREIGN KEY(id_consulta) REFERENCES consulta(id_consulta),
INDEX id_empleado(id_empleado)
);
select* from empleado_consulta;
select id_empleado from empleado_consulta;


insert into empleado_consulta values ('1','4'); 
insert into empleado_consulta values ('3','6');
insert into empleado_consulta(id_consulta,id_empleado) values ('6','7');
insert into empleado_consulta(id_consulta,id_empleado) values ('7','9');


update empleado_consulta 
    set id_consulta= '1'
    where id_empleado = '7' ;
update empleado_consulta 
    set id_empleado= '6'
    where id_consulta = '3' ;

delete from empleado_consulta where id_consulta = '6';
delete from empleado_consulta where id_empleado = '4';
drop index nombres_2 on medico;
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es autoexplicativo. No puedes insertar datos en esa tabla sin que exista el valor relacionado en la otra, de modo que primero deberás crear los datos necesarios en la/s tabla/s relacionada/s y por último en la deseada. En resumen: intentas crear una relación entre dos tablas a valores que no existen. Eso no es posible hasta que esos valores existan en las tablas.

Comment: Redactando respuesta (me está llevando MUCHO tiempo debido a la cantidad de tablas relacionadas que tienes).

Comment: ``@Max`` no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta y de darle positivamente es muy buena respuesta la de @OscarGarcia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de poder insertar valores en una tabla cuyos campos están relacionados con otras tablas deberás asegurarte que dichos valores existen. En caso no de existir el servidor te mostrará el mensaje de error que recibiste para indicarte que no puedes insertar datos en la tabla que hagan referencia a registros que no existen en las otras tablas.

De modo que en tus inserciones:

```
insert into empleado_consulta values ('1','4'); 
insert into empleado_consulta values ('3','6');
insert into empleado_consulta(id_consulta,id_empleado) values ('6','7');
insert into empleado_consulta(id_consulta,id_empleado) values ('7','9');
```

Necesitarás haber creado previamente las consultas cuya `id_consulta` sean 1, 3, 6 y 7 y los empleados cuyos `id_empleado` sean 4, 6, 7 y 9:

```
INSERT INTO consulta (
  id_consulta, exp_paciente, jvpm_medico, fecha_consulta, tipo
) VALUES (
  1, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
), (
  3, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
), (
  6, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
), (
  7, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
);

INSERT INTO empleado (
  id_empleado, id_cargo, nombres, apellidos, dui, telefono, direccion
) VALUES (
  4, 1, 'Empleado 1', '', '', '', ''
), (
  6, 1, 'Empleado 2', '', '', '', ''
), (
  7, 1, 'Empleado 3', '', '', '', ''
), (
  9, 1, 'Empleado 4', '', '', '', ''
);
```

Para poder insertar esos registros, deberás haber creado previamente todos los registros en las tablas relacionadas.

El código SQL completo para poder reproducir tu problema fue:

```
INSERT INTO cargo (
  id_cargo, descripcion
) VALUES (
  1, 'Director'
);

INSERT INTO empleado (
  id_empleado, id_cargo, nombres, apellidos, dui, telefono, direccion
) VALUES (
  4, 1, 'Empleado 1', '', '', '', ''
), (
  6, 1, 'Empleado 2', '', '', '', ''
), (
  7, 1, 'Empleado 3', '', '', '', ''
), (
  9, 1, 'Empleado 4', '', '', '', ''
);

INSERT INTO paciente (
  expediente, nombres, apellidos, telefono1, direccion, telefono_contacto
) VALUES (
  1, 'Nombre', 'Apellidos', '', '', ''
);

INSERT INTO especialidad (
  idespecialidad, descripcion
) VALUES (
  1, 'Especialidad'
);

INSERT INTO medico (
  jvpm, id_especialidad, nombres, apellidos, telefono1, telefono2, direccion
) VALUES (
  1, 1, 'Nombres', '', '', '', ''
);

INSERT INTO consulta (
  id_consulta, exp_paciente, jvpm_medico, fecha_consulta, tipo
) VALUES (
  1, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
), (
  3, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
), (
  6, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
), (
  7, 1, 1, '2022-01-01', '...'
);
```

Puedes ver el código SQL funcionando en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4tzZtTW9n5TjqxyAJ1beHM/0

Comment: muy buena respuesta amigo, yo te la vote positivamente esta mañana :)